# How can I select two columns in a query and order them by a third column?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

Basically, is there a way to do this?

```
select B,C,SUM(I) group by B,C order by L
```

I've added the row numbers to L, but if there's a way to get row numbers in the formula, I'd love to know. Thanks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desiredo output

Comment: @Abject Failure, need your feedback on provided answers.

Answer (score 1):

try perhaps:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(A:L, 
 "select B,C,sum(I),L 
  where B is not null 
  group by B,C,L 
  order by L 
  label sum(I)''", 0), 999^99, 3)
```

Comment: I liked the Q and your answer. Used your formula to get results with no duplicates for columns 1,2.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will group by 2 columns and sort by the 3-d column.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(
  FILTER({B:B,C:C,I:I,VLOOKUP(B:B&C:C,{B:B&C:C,L:L},2,)},B:B<>""),
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3),Col4
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2,Col4 
  order by Col4", 1), 999^99, 3)
```

- `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` to hide sort column
- `FILTER` + `VLOOKUP` to select first entries of column 3 (L) in order to skip duplicates.